# Does the RPI v2 B and the RPIv4 B have the same pinouts?

Tags: gpio, hardware

**Question**: Do the RPI v2 B and the RPIv4 B have the same pinouts?

example: https://www.etechnophiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/R-Pi-4-GPIO-Pinout-1-768x572.jpg?ezimgfmt=ng:webp/ngcb40

Answer (score 0):

Your type identification is wrong.

If the question is about the Pi2B versus the Pi4B then they have the same 40 pin header and pinout.

Answer (score 0):

Yo.

The physical interface and default modes are identical across all models with 40 pin headers.

The BCM2711 SOC used on the Pi4 allows some pins to be configured in different modes which are unavailable on earlier models.